# pulls into the diner('s parking lot)

Tags: grammar

Are both these possible or only the second? I have found examples with the first, but does it make sense?

1. Ben pulls into the diner.
2. Ben pulls into the diner's parking lot.

Ben is in a car, by the way.

Comment: Either is fine.  #2 is only really necessary if your listener needs to know something about the parking lot or something that happened there.  When we drive somewhere we can *pull into* the destination after we arrive.  There is a lot leeway with this usage. *I pulled into Ben's house, Ben's driveway, Ben's yard, Ben's apartment, Ben's place.*  Your usage will probably depend on the rest of the story.  For example, if there is tree limb blocking Ben's driveway and I plan on discussing it with Ben, then driveway might work best.

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct. The default meaning of “Ben pulls into the diner” is indeed “Ben pulls into (the parking lot of) the diner.”

If Ben actually drove his car directly into the building, you would need to state that explicitly since that would be a very strange thing for Ben to do.

Comment: I would always add 'into the parking lot of the diner'. We just had a [case in my town](https://www.bristolpost.co.uk/news/bristol-news/tesla-goes-flying-window-shop-6905246) (Bristol UK) where an elderly driver drove a Tesla straight into the front of a furniture store and wound up right at the back. She is currently in hospital. Looks like a very big bill for the damage. You could say she pulled in to the furniture store.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey no, nobody in their right mind would hear "pulled into the furniture store" and imagine the story you described. In that case, you absolutely would need more explanatory details; the default meaning of "pulled into the furniture store" would be pulling into the parking lot of said store.

Comment: @Esther Maybe it's a US-British thing. If I said I pulled into a supermarket, people would probably guess what I meant (I pulled into the car park of the supermarket), but strictly speaking a literal listener would note the other meaning.